# Simple use case for Pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a simple query on a Pandas dataframe

```
A B C
0 1 2.1
0 2 3.0
0 3 4.0
1 0 4.0
```

I want to pick all rows `WHERE A=0 and B>1` so I would expect as output

```
A B C
0 2 3.0
0 3 4.0
```

I define my DataFrame as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2.1}, {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 3.0}, {'A': 0, 'B': 3, 'C': 4.0}, {'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'C': 4.0}])
```

Then do the following query

```
df[ (df["A"] == 0) & (df["B"] > 1) ]

   A  B    C
1  0  2  3.0
2  0  3  4.0
```

It works but it's slow in my real use case since there many more rows.

After going through the pandas [MultiIndexing doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced), I'm not clear how I use indexes to improve the performance of the above query. Is there a way I can improve the performance of the above query using indexes?

Comment: Unlike database indexes, Pands indexes do not (and were not meant to) improve the performance of queries.

Comment: @DyZ That's interesting, this is my first time using Pandas. Is there a similar concept to a database index in Pandas for query optimization?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no. At least not in pandas. But see my answer.

Comment: Then how/why do people use pandas for applications with large amounts of data?

Comment: They either don't, or they are patient.

Comment: Interesting, it appears I have chosen the wrong tool then. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Mike you might be interested in my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103516/dataframe-hierachical-indexing-speedup/49103701#49103701 Your case might need more fine-grined work, though. Also, I am not sure how similar is your toy example to your real dataset. (if it is similar, the query optimization seems doable to me.)

Answer (score 2):

You can query the underlying numpy array instead of the original dataframe:

```
%timeit df[(df["A"] == 0) & (df["B"] > 1) ]
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop

ar = df.values
%timeit ar[(ar[:,0] == 0) & (ar[:,1] > 1)]
#100000 loops, best of 3: 11.5 µs per loop
```

If you want to preserve the original index, convert it to a column before running the query and then back to the index.

Comment: This is not fast when the rows are plenty. (It is faster but not really fast as you shown.)

Comment: @Tai What is _really fast_, then?

Comment: What you shown is 100 faster.  I used your method in a 100000 row dataset and it is just 30-40% faster/

Comment: Try `df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randint(0,2, 100000),
 "B": np.random.randint(0,10, 100000),
 "C": np.random.rand(100000) })`

Comment: What I show is merely 100 times faster, and it is still faster than the original approach. I never claimed it is going to be _much_ faster.

Comment: Yes, I know you did not claim it but it is misleading especially when OP said his/her dataset is large.

Comment: @Tai have an 80% improvement with _your_ data.

Comment: If you include `ar = df.values` in your timeit, It is slower (at least it was for me)