# Dataframe hierarchical indexing speedup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|    |            |    type    | payment    | 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
| id | res_number |            |            | 
+----+------------+------------+------------+
|  a |     1      |    toys    | 20000      |
|    |     2      |  clothing  | 30000      |
|    |     3      |    food    | 40000      |
|  b |     4      |    food    | 40000      |
|    |     5      |   laptop   | 30000      |
+----+------------+------------+------------+
```

as you can see id, and res_number are hierachical row value, and type, payment are normal columns value. What i want to get is below.

```
array([['toys', 20000],
   ['clothing', 30000],
   ['food', 40000]])
```

It indexed by 'id(=a)' no matter what 'res_number' came, and i know that

```
df.loc[['a']].values
```

perfectly works for it. But the speed of indexing is too slow... i have to index 150000 values.

so i indexed dataframe by

```
df.iloc[1].values
```

but it only brought

```
array(['toys', 20000])
```

is there any indexing method more faster in indexing hierarchical structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.DataFrame.xs`

```
df.xs('a').values
```

**Option 2**
`pd.DataFrame.loc`

```
df.loc['a'].values
```

**Option 3**
`pd.DataFrame.query`

```
df.query('ilevel_0 == \'a\'').values
```

**Option 4**
A bit more roundabout, use `pd.MultiIndex.get_level_values` to create a mask:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a'].values
```

```
array([['toys', 20000],
       ['clothing', 30000],
       ['food', 40000]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Do you mind providing some evidence that your methods are performant? I remember you told me query is slow someday. I don't know why you listed here. Maybe there are some situations that it is faster that people don't know. Maybe we can learn from you :P

Comment: @Tai Um, context matters, don't you think?

Comment: Think so. Just a bit curious why you added here :P

Comment: @Tai Why not, it's a pretty decent option _in this case_.

Comment: I am not sure that it fits the context here as the op asks for methods better than op's `loc` method in his/her use case. I expect the methods proposed can at least outperform `loc` method in some cases. I have not yet found a case with both op's dataset and my datasets. That's why I am thinking maybe you could provide something more concrete as you propose it here. Thought you might have done some experiments.

Comment: @Tai Ah, didn't see the performance requirement :) I think `xs` should still do pretty nicely. If not, Scott's `loc(axis=0)` would be another performant alternative.

Comment: Got you :P Misunderstanding it is.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 5

Use .loc with axis parameter

```
 df.loc(axis=0)['a',:].values
```

Output:

```
array([['toys', 20000],
       ['clothing', 30000],
       ['food', 40000]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option. Keep an extra dictionary of the beginning and ending indices of each group. (
**Assume the index is sorted. )**

**Option 1** Use the first and the last index in a group to query with `iloc`.

```
d = {k: slice(v[0], v[-1]+1) for k, v in df.groupby("id").indices.items()}
df.iloc[d["b"]]

array([['food', 40000],
       ['laptop', 30000]], dtype=object)
```

**Option 2** Use the first and the last index to query with `numpy`'s index slicing on `df.values`.

```
df.values[d["a"]]
```

Timing

```
df_testing = pd.DataFrame({"id": [str(v) for v in np.random.randint(0, 100, 150000)],
                        "res_number": np.arange(150000),
                        "payment": [v for v in np.random.randint(0, 100000, 150000)]}
             ).set_index(["id","res_number"]).sort_index()
d = {k: slice(v[0], v[-1]+1) for k, v in df_testing.groupby("id").indices.items()}
# by COLDSPEED
%timeit df_testing.xs('5').values
303 µs ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# by OP
%timeit df_testing.loc['5'].values
358 µs ± 22.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# Tai 1
%timeit df_testing.iloc[d["5"]].values 
130 µs ± 3.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# Tai 2
%timeit df_testing.values[d["5"]] 
7.26 µs ± 845 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

However, getting `d` is not costless.

```
%timeit {k: slice(v[0], v[-1]+1) for k, v in df_testing.groupby("id").indices.items()}
16.3 ms ± 6.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Whether creating an extra lookup table d worth it?**

The cost of creating the index will be spread on the gain from doing queries. In my toy dataset, it will be 16.3 ms / (300 us - 7 us) ≈ 56 queries to recover the cost of creating the index.

Again, the index needs to be sorted.

Comment: @권효섭 I seem to have done something similar to what you want with `iloc` initially. Please take a look at my answer if you have time.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to generate an "index" lookup with `d`... seems redundant when you consider `df.index` already _is_ a dictionary and `xs` and `loc` are just neat wrappers to do exactly what you're doing here, minus all the unnecessary overhead (of a groupby that too, wow).

Comment: Hmm, I also see that generating the mapping is 1000x more expensive than the indexing operation. Definitely not worth it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ an application  could be the person needs to run queries for more than 1000 times I think.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the cost of creating the index will be spread on the gain from doing queries. In my toy dataset, it will be 16.3 ms / (300 us - 7 us) = 56 queries to recover the cost of creating the index.